# HTML 5 form browser compatibility issue with Internet Explorer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Why HTML5 forms are not compatible on IE 9?

I don't see forms validated on Internet explorer 9.
It works fine on FF, Chrome, and Safari, but not on Internet Explorer.

Comment: WAAAAY too vague.  We need much more information to be of any help.  But for a quick, general answer:  IE is horrible and is always a couple versions behind everyone else as far as features and support.

Comment: Mike, he did mention `form validation` what is a new HTML5 feature. IE does not support it.

Comment: HTML5 forms are not fully supported in any browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Nida Hafeez,

Check out this:
http://html5readiness.com

You should not go with HTML5 Validation, I won't recommend.

Always remember that users can overcome client side validation, based on different browser type, version and enable/disable javascript or other client side capabilities.

Comment: No matter what's the script, on every user input server side validations **always** have to be done!

Answer (score 7):

Internet Explorer is lacking most of the HTML5 features, that's why you are having problems with it.

See **[this](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie09.html)** site, to find out, what IE9 is compatible with:

**Forms**

```
input type=text             Partial         
input type=search           No      
input type=tel              No      
input type=url              No      
input type=email            No      
input type=datetime         No      
input type=date             No      
input type=month            No      
input type=week             No      
input type=time             No      
input type=datetime-local   No      
input type=number           No      
input type=range            No      
input type=color            No      
input type=checkbox         Yes         
input type=image            Yes         
input type=file             Partial         
textarea                    Partial         
select                      Partial         
fieldset                    Partial         
datalist                    No      
keygen                      No      
output                      No      
progress                    No      
meter                       No
```

**Fields**

```
Field validation                    No      
Association of controls and forms   No      
Other attributes                    No      
CSS selectors                       No      
Events                              Partial
```

```
Form validation     No
```

Comment: +1 for your answer ...and its  looks like new user accepting the answer according to the reputation .. your answer is more helpful than quentine

Answer (score 4):

Because IE9 is (relatively) old, Microsoft is cautious about supporting new standards, and HTML5 is bleeding edge.

Answer (score 1):

It seems [form validation](http://caniuse.com/form-validation) is not supported until IE 10.0

There should be a [polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) that allows you to achieve what you would like.

Answer (score 1):

many feature of the html 5 form is not supported by many browser check

check [**A FORM OF MADNESS**](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html)

and 
Browser Support for New HTML5 Input Types

[image]

source [Browser Support for New HTML5 Input Types](http://wufoo.com/html5/)

Answer (score 0):

Because [IE9 is not a Modern Browser](http://people.mozilla.com/~prouget/ie9/)

Answer (score 0):

maybe an html5 enabler will work for you check this http://html5doctor.com/how-to-get-html5-working-in-ie-and-firefox-2/

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to check the browser compability before using html5 elements.